# How do I daemonify my daemon?

Tags: python, application-development, programming, services

As part of the Ubuntu Accomplishments system I have a daemon that runs as well as a client that connects to it. The daemon is written in Python (using Twisted) and provides a dbus service and a means of processing requests from the clients.

Right now the daemon is just a program I run before I run the client and it sets up the dbus service and provides an API that can be used by the clients.

I want to transform this into something that can be installed and run as a system service for the user's session (e.g. starting on boot) and providing a means to start and stop it etc.

The problem is, I am not sure what I need to do to properly daemonify it so it can run as this service. I wanted to ask if others can provide some guidance. Some things I need to ask:

- How can I treat it as a service that is run for the current user service (not a system service right now)?
- How do I ensure I can start, stop, and restart this session service?
- When packaging this, how do I ensure that it installs it as a service for the user's session and is started on login etc?

In responding, if you can point me to specific examples or solutions I need to implement, that would be helpful. :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found several how-to's just by running a Google search:

http://www.enderunix.org/docs/eng/daemon.php

http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66012-fork-a-daemon-process-on-unix/

http://cjh.polyplex.org/software/daemon.pdf

I hope they can help you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for the recommended links. I guess the first thing I am trying to figure out is if I can do this easily using Twisted. I see there is something called twistd which might help here, but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

A daemon is basically a program with no direct user interaction... So there is nothing really specific about it. Nevertheless, you have to take care about some keys points :

- any output or log should go to syslog, not the standard output
- at startup, create a pid file under /var/run. And clear it at shutdown.
- you have to write a service supervision file, to be located in /etc/init.d (scripts for existing daemon are a good source of inspiration). This script usually has to start the daemon under the right user, provide it with the right configuration files and so on.
- your process might begin with a fork, to detach from the calling process, but I'm not really sure about that, especially for a python program.